# Graph IPv4 and IPv6 comparison traffic

Tags: linux, networking

I'm looking for some tool that allows me to see how much traffic is going via IPv4 and IPv6 on my network. I would basically like to have something like a pie chart with this two measures. I've been reading about a custom plugin with Munin but I would like to know is there's another choice, specially with Cacti.

Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS should it run on? Or are you looking for a webapp?

Comment: It might be Ubuntu or some other Linux flavour

Answer (score 1):

Try Scrutinizer: http://www.plixer.com/Scrutinizer-Netflow-Sflow/scrutinizer.html

I used it for a while to monitor bandwidth over site2site VPN tunnels. You can really dig into different types of traffic, not 100% sure on IPv4 & 6 but its a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco has a list of NetFlow software packages (which work with various hardware vendor platforms not just Cisco) on their website split into three categories which I have provided links to below, it forms a good comprehensive list of NetFlow collectors and analyzers;

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-netflow/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff72b.html

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-netflow/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff728.html

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-netflow/networking_solutions_products_genericcontent0900aecd805ff720.html

Cacti isn't able to process NetFlow information as far as I know. If you two seperate interfaces for IPv4 and IPv6 traffic though then you can use Cacti (because it can only graph an interfaces as a whole, not specific IP ranges or versions etc).